# Rails Action Mailer with sidekiq not finding association in template on first call

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actionmailer, sidekiq

I have setup my notifications so after I create a trade it kicks the creations of the notification to sidekiq. Then in the notification model it sends the email in a after_create callback. The problem is that when it triggers the mail, it says sender is not found. It retriggers and eventually sends the email but I want it to send on the first time and I don't get why it's not picking up the sender. It definitely exists in the database.

Here are all the related files and the error.

app/models/trade.rb

```
class Trade < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :notifications, as: :notifiable
  after_create :notify_receiver, :create_public_activity

  def notify_receiver
    Notification.delay.create(notifiable_id: id, notifiable_type: self.class.name, key: 'initiate_trade', user_id: receiver.user_id)
  end
end
```

app/models/notifications.rb

```
class Notification < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :notifiable, polymorphic: true
  belongs_to :user

  after_create :send_email

  def send_email
    case key
    when 'initiate_trade'
      NotificationMailer.initiate_trade(self).deliver_now
    end
  end
end
```

app/views/notification_mailer/initiate_trade.html.haml

```
= "#{@notification.notifiable.sender.player.full_name} "

wants to trade
= " #{@notification.notifiable.offered_player_league_countries.joins(:country).select("countries.name").map {|c| c.name}.join(', ')} "
for
= " #{@notification.notifiable.requested_player_league_countries.joins(:country).select("countries.name").map {|c| c.name}.join(', ')}."
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Would this help?

```
def notify_receiver
  reload
  Notification.delay.create(notifiable_id: id, notifiable_type: self.class.name, key: 'initiate_trade', user_id: receiver.user_id)
end
```

I'd guess that after_create hook does not automatically reload record, and thus notifiable is still `nil` in that phase. Saying `reload` before creating the job 
should fix the issue, right?

Comment: Doofus me, reload was in wrong place. Id is already passed to Notification class, and reloading in the worker would not help. 

Also you might want to inspect value of id above, and maybe even abort if it's nil: `fail 'id not set' if id.nil?` could be worthwhile before calling Notification.delay